# C++ error typedef cannot be overloaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp

I have this c++ programm and for some reason it wont compile . I am using XP with VS 2005 .

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MainThread.h"

HANDLE  hStopEvent = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    return 0;
}

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hStopEvent'
error C2377: 'HANDLE' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
see declaration of 'HANDLE'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: The problem will be in your header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error is most likely because you've got a problem in the header file, which has resulted in the compiler treating the first thing it finds in the source file as an identifier.

Something like having an unfinished struct or class definition:

```
struct blah {
    int a;
} // MISSING ';'
```

If you can't see it, I suggest posting the header file.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... it's the redefinition thing that threw me, but you can get that without explicitly redefining it...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to

```
#include <Windows.h>
```